# Is "brings all the boys to the yard" an idiom? How to find out if a phrase is an idiom or not

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms, idiom-meaning

Recently, I have had a debate with a friend that "brings all the boys to the yard" is an idiom and he refuses to accept it. Since this has been used as a part of a [rapper's lyrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milkshake_(song)), he says this is not an idiom. All in all, is it an idiom and how to find out if some phrases are idioms or not? Is there a specific dictionary or a thesaurus?

The lyrics go like this:

> My milkshake brings all the boys to the yard,
> And they're like
> It's better than yours,
> Damn right,
> It's better than yours,
> I can teach you,
> But I have to charge
>
> <sub>See full lyrics at [AZLyrics.com](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/kelis/milkshake.html)</sub>

Comment: According to the _Dictionary of English Grammar_ an idiom is "_a string of words having a meaning that is not deducible from the meanings of the individual words_." To determine whether "_brings all the boys to the yard_" is an idiom by this definition we would need to know its context. Can you provide the whole sentence or, optimally, a link to the entire lyrics?

Comment: @Shoe here is the lyric that has it: "My milkshake brings all the boys to the yard, and their life Is better than yours, damn right is better than yours, I can teach you, but I have to charge.""

Comment: The string is grammatical, but 'the boys' and 'the yard' no longer need antecedents (for listeners who have heard it before), so the expression has become idiomatic.  It now means that something is 'seductive'.

Comment: There is no way to prove that a certain sequence of words is *not* an idiom, since the "audience" for the idiom can be exceedingly small.  Some phrases are idioms within a single family or company or social group, in that they call forth a meaning over and above the meanings of the individual words.  A phrase does not have to have a "special" meaning to the entire English-speaking population to be an idiom to some population.

Comment: You and your friend should agree on an idiom dictionary. Then, whenever there is a debate, consult the dictionary. Alternatively, look up and agree on a definition of "idiom" . Then use the definition to test whether a particular instance is an idiom.

Comment: Why not just search on Google making sure to put the expression in quotes and exclude keywords that are obviously related to the song you mention, e.g. *"brings all the boys to the yard" -rap -kelis -song* to get usages without the rapper (Kelis) etc. Likewise search with a date range i.e. up to the date when the track was releases and see how many hits you get.

Comment: @Silenus my whole point of this question was to know if there is any kind of dictionary for this matter or not.

Comment: @k1eran i am just wondering if first of all, whether or not it is an idiom and secondly, if it is only idiom in its context or can be used in other cases as well.

Comment: @HotLicks so what is your solution?

Comment: @lonesome what I meant was that if you get no (or very few) hits prior to 2002 (or whenever the song came out) it gives us a "clue" whether it was a common idiom prior to the song. And/or  doing searches without the singer and related keywords gives you a second clue. Ngrams also give you an early indication. This all requires a little judgement and interpretation of course.

Comment: @lonesome - Why do you need a "solution"?

Comment: "The burden of proof lies on the prosecution." Your friend sucks at arguing if they 'refuse to accept it' without providing evidence to the contrary. However, if you're the one that asserted this, the onus is on you. That's your bad ;)

Comment: @HotLicks I thought this site is to answer questions and solve problems and not for fun.

Comment: @lonesome - As it is we have no idea why you need to know if a given phrase is an idiom.  Without knowing that it's hard to offer any advice on how to make this determination.  (Simply winning an argument with a friend is not really a valid "reason".)

Comment: @HotLicks why do you think it is just an argument? dont you think that even so, it will benefits me in future and others by reading this question?

Comment: @lonesome - Like I said, **why** do you need a solution?  If you want any sort of reasonable answer you need to explain your needs.

Comment: @HotLicks because I asked a question? to prevent for future references?

Answer (score 2):

Despite the literal nature of the music video, it's not literal. In fact, trying to rationalize a literal explanation is a bit absurd, as [you can see here](https://thebrowntweedsociety.com/2011/09/17/tasting-the-goods-a-brief-psycho-social-analysis-of-kelis%E2%80%99s-%E2%80%9Cmilkshake%E2%80%9D/).

In case you're still not convinced it's not literal, read Kelis's response in a [recent interview](https://www.theguardian.com/music/2016/may/23/kelis-i-never-made-a-milkshake-forgotten-fields-kendal-calling) (emphasis mine):

> > What would go in a Kelis milkshake? Apart from milk, obviously …
>
> **I don’t think I’ve ever made a milkshake.** I made a smoothie the other day that was really good – protein powder, spinach, orange, and crushed ice with a little bit of honey and coconut water.

However, I wouldn't describe it an idiom. I like how [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milkshake_(song)) describes it:

> According to Kelis, "milkshake" in the song is used as a metaphor for "something that makes women special." The song is noted for its euphemistic chorus and low beat R&B sound.

It doesn't have a concrete meaning, which is typical for many songs.

---

---

As for idiom dictionaries, yes, they exist. Wikipedia has a [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiom_dictionary) about it, and you can find a lot by [searching](https://www.google.com/#q=dictionary+of+idioms).

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_idioms) has a large list of idioms too.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams) is a useful tool for this sort of problem. Using "boys to the yard" as a search term, we get:

[image: Search results for "boys to the yard"]

As you can see, the number of occurences is miniscule, so it is fairly safe to assume that *brings all the boys to the yard* is not idiomatic.

Unfortunately, the maximum number of words allowed is five, so we cannot search for the entire phrase.

Comment: "How to find out if a phrase is an idiom or not?" Use ngram, +1. Why is this DVed? "minuscule", indeed. This is like "off the charts" non-existent.

Comment: When you can see square shapes in an ngram, you know something's off.